# Issues with force download in php

Tags: php, download

I have written a PHP script to force download files to users. Everything works great with one exception, **the file is not completely downloaded** let's say there is a 10 MB mp3 file downloading, but it stops after 5 MB and displays download completed.

My site host is godaddy.com
And the code is below

```
<?php
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
}

if ( isset ( $_REQUEST['file_name'] )) {
    $filename = basename($_REQUEST['file_name']);
    $filesize = filesize("mp3gallery/".$_REQUEST['file_name']);

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false);
    header("Content-length: $filesize");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');

    $read_file = "mp3gallery/".$_REQUEST['file_name'];




    function readfile_chunked($filename,$retbytes=true) {
        $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); // how many bytes per chunk
        $buffer = '';
        $cnt =0;
        // $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        if ($handle === false) {
            return false;
        }
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
            echo $buffer;
            ob_flush(); 
            flush(); 
            if ($retbytes) {
                $cnt += strlen($buffer);
            }
        }
            $status = fclose($handle);
        if ($retbytes && $status) {
            return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does.
        }
        return $status;

   }
   readfile_chunked($read_file,true); 
}
?>
```

Please Help.........

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that your script times out.

So what can you do?

- Change the time limit (Probably not possible, because your hoster won't let you)
- Speed things up

Regarding the latter: is there a specific reason why you don't just use [`fpassthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php)? I'd expect it to have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  function download( $data , $fName ) {
         header( sprintf( 'Expires: %s' , strftime( '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT' , strtotime( '+1 year' , time() ) ) ) );
         header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate' );
         header( 'Pragma: public, no-cache' );
         header( sprintf( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="%s"' , $fName ) );
         header( sprintf( 'Content-Description: %s' , uniqid() ) );
         if ( is_file( $data ) ) {
                $filePath = sprintf( '%s/%s' , $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] , $data );
                if ( file_exists( $data ) ) {
                       if ( version_compare( PHP_VERSION , '5.3.0' , '<' ) )
                              header( sprintf( 'Content-Type: %s' , mime_content_type( $filePath ) ) );
                       else
                              header( sprintf( 'Content-Type: %s' , finfo_file( finfo_open( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE ) , $filePath ) ) );
                       header( sprintf( 'Content-Length: %d' , filesize( $filePath ) ) );
                       readfile( $data );
                }
         } else {
                echo $data;
         }
  }
```

Comment: You might want to add we the OP should try this. What does your code do better?