# Force Download with Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i want to have force download functionality only with Flash AS3, is it possible ?? i tried google but failed. here it is my as3 code......

```
var file_URLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("mp3gallery/" + url);
var content_header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type: application/force-download");
var attach_header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc.mp3");

            file_URLRequest.requestHeaders.push(content_header);
            file_URLRequest.requestHeaders.push(attach_header);
            file_URLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            navigateToURL(file_URLRequest, '_blank');
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need it only in AS3? Would a simple navigateToURL to a server side page that serves your mp3 file to the browser not be sufficient?

Comment: there are some plugins available in browser to play mp3 files directly in browser , and i don't want that.......... i tried php but some issues in that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458449/issues-with-force-download-in-php

Comment: You should be doing it in php. The response header will have content-disposition: attachment, but if there is a browser plugin, I doubt it will bypass that plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is [directly from the docs](http://www.igorcosta.com/flex3/doc/flash/net/FileReference.html#download%28%29):

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.FileFilter;

public class FileReference_download extends Sprite {
    private var downloadURL:URLRequest;
    private var fileName:String = "SomeFile.pdf";
    private var file:FileReference;

    public function FileReference_download() {
        downloadURL = new URLRequest();
        downloadURL.url = "http://www.[yourDomain].com/SomeFile.pdf";
        file = new FileReference();
        configureListeners(file);
        file.download(downloadURL, fileName);
    }

    private function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void {
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, cancelHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
    }

    private function cancelHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("cancelHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("completeHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function openHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("openHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
        var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
        trace("progressHandler name=" + file.name + " bytesLoaded=" + event.bytesLoaded + " bytesTotal=" + event.bytesTotal);
    }

    private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
        trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function selectHandler(event:Event):void {
        var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
        trace("selectHandler: name=" + file.name + " URL=" + downloadURL.url);
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: this could not work if used this way, because an action of the user (a click) may be required. So you should move the code contained in the constructor to a method (click handler). Of course, in this case `btn` is the instance name of a movieclip placed on stage, while `FileReference_download` is the DocumentClass.

```
 public function FileReference_download() {
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, downloadMyFile);
        }

        private function downloadMyFile(e:MouseEvent){
            downloadURL = new URLRequest();
            downloadURL.url = "http://www.[yourDomain].com/SomeFile.pdf";
            file = new FileReference();
            configureListeners(file);
            file.download(downloadURL, fileName);
        }
```