# File Reference won't work in webpage

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a .SWF file that if I test by itself outside of a browser the file reference works just fine. However if I test inside a browser I get nothing.

Is there some publish setting that should be checked?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to access an external file from within the SWF file, and when you run the SWF, the file is loaded, but not when you run the SWF in a browser? Could you provide the part of the code where you mention the reference?

Comment: One question: does it work alone? Or the user must click a button? If it is supposed to work alone it won't work in the browser (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462458/force-download-with-flash-as3/8463693#8463693).

Answer (score 1):

If FileReference is supposed to work in the browser without user interaction (eg. a button click), for security restrictions it won't work.